# Safari error "Functions cannot be declared in a nested block in strict mode"

Tags: reactjs, redux, safari

My `React` app crashes in `Safari 9` and `10`.

I completely understand what does this error mean.
But the problem is that it is not in my code, the wrong code is in `node modules` so I can't fix it. In my case there's function declared inside "`if`" in `Redux` library:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    function miniKindOf(val) { 
     ...
    }
}
```

What can I do to make my app work? Maybe there are any polyfills for `Safari`?

Comment: you can try by moving if condition to inside your `minikindof` function.

Comment: As I said, it's node modules, it doesn't make sense to change code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Released in Redux 4.1.1

---

Seems there is an open issue for it: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/4089

I will ping the maintainers and see if we can get a fix out soon

In the meantime I can only suggest you use the production build instead of the development build.

Comment: Thanks, I see. There's already PR for this but not released yet.

Comment: This has been released as 4.1.1